# Prove this language is not context-free

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar

Let $L = \{ww^Rw|w \in \{ a, b, c\}^*\}$

I am using the pumping lemma for CF languages. [...]

I split the string into 4 regions, which we'll call 1, 2, 3, & 4.

aaaa...aabb..bbbaaa...aaabbb....bbb

|.....1.....||.....2.....||....3....||.....4.....|

This part of the proof is where I am not sure what to do, I need to list the possible cases but I am not exactly sure what they would be. v, y could overlap I suppose, and be in each region, would that be conclusive? I guess I am not sure how many cases I should be covering here and what regions they should involve.

Edit: I should also mention that maybe it would be more suitable if my sample string contained some c's.

Comment: What is $w^R$? The string reversed?

Comment: Yes, it is the string w but reversed.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: If $p$ is the pumping length, try starting with $a^pb^pc^{2p}b^pa^{2p}b^pc^p$; this is in $L$ with $w=a^pb^pc^p$.

Comment: Would this be the right idea? http://i.imgur.com/C4A8Fg1.jpg

Comment: @AppreciateIt: You’re going in the right general direction, but you need to go into quite a bit more detail really to justify the conclusions that the pumped strings are not in $L$, and I think that you’ll need more cases. It will help to realize that since $|vxy|\le p$, $vxy$ must lie in the initial $a^pb^p$, in the first $b^pc^p$, in the $c^{2p}$, in the $c^pb^p$, in the $b^pa^p$, in the $a^{2p}$, in the second $a^pb^p$, or in the second $b^pc^p$. Show that in each of these cases there is some way to pump that takes the string out of $L$.

Comment: @AppreciateIt: You’re very welcome.